# Scala MongoDB read using Observable API

Tags: mongodb, scala

Here is Java developer learning Scala. 
I wrote this ugly code to deal with async Observable API to read values from MongoDB. I'm sure there is more elegant solution. Throwing it out here for smarter folk to correct my solution:

```
def read = Action { request =>
    val dbUrl = config.getString("mongodb.uri").getOrElse(throw new IllegalStateException("Configure mongodb.uriin application.conf"))
    val mongoClient = MongoClient(dbUrl)

    val database= mongoClient.getDatabase("mydatabase")
    val collection = database.getCollection("mycollection")

    val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
    var done = false;

    collection.find().subscribe(
      (doc: Document) => builder.append(doc.toJson()+", \n"),              // onNext
      (error: Throwable) => println(s"Query failed: ${error.getMessage}"), // onError
      () => done = true // Complete
    )

    while(!done) { Thread.sleep(100) }

    Created(builder.toString())

}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Where in the code? What's the error messages?

Comment: You can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html